# integral constant next to theta

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a bit stuck on this practice question for an upcoming integration exam (calculus 1).

Here is the integral:

$$\int_ {0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\cos(3\theta)d\theta}$$

What confuses me is the 3 next to the theta. When I evaluated the integral, I assumed you would do as follows, multiplying the limits by three:
$$2\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)-2\sin(\theta)$$ 
However this did not lead to the correct answer. Where did I go wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to put your post in latex form; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \cos (ax) = -a \sin (ax) \implies \int \cos (ax) = \frac{\sin (ax)}{a}$$

Answer (score 0):

using substitution $t=3\theta,dt=3d\theta$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 2\cos3\theta d\theta=
\int_0^{3\pi/2} \frac{2}3\cos t d t
\frac{2}3\int_0^{3\pi/2} \cos t d t=
\frac{2}3\sin t\Bigg|_0^{3\pi/2}=-\frac{2}3$$